# GroupingView in Ext.Net V2.X show error

Tags: c#, javascript, ext.net

I am new with Ext.Net V1.X tool and my old project woking fine, but when I update Ext.Net DLL set V2.X. Number of control generate errors.

> Error :58 The type or namespace name 'GroupingView' does not exist in
>   the namespace 'Ext.Net' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

```
<View> <ext:GroupingView ID="gridView" HideGroupedColumn="true" ForceFit="true" > <Listeners> <Refresh Handler="UncheckCheckHeader(#{checkSelectionModel});" /> </Listeners> <GetRowClass Fn="getRowClass" /> </ext:GroupingView> </View>
```

---

Comment: Any suggestion to migrate V1.X application with V2.X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GroupingView has been removed in v2. Please use a Grouping feature, see #23 in the [BREAKING_CHANGES](http://examples.ext.net/#/Getting_Started/Release_Documents/BREAKING_CHANGES/) file.

[Here](http://forums.ext.net/showthread.php?18358#post79239) are my best thoughts regarding migrating to v2 from v1.